# How to compute that $\mathcal{L}_Vg_{ij}=g_{ik}\nabla_jV^k+g_{jk}\nabla_iV^k$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

How to compute that $\mathcal{L}_Vg_{ij}=g_{ik}\nabla_jV^k+g_{jk}\nabla_iV^k$ ?

The $g_{ij}$ is Riemannian metric, $V=V^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$ is vector flied ,$\mathcal{L}_Vg$  is Lie derivative.

In fact ,according to the Wiki, I think the $\mathcal{L}_Vg_{ij}=V^k\nabla_k {g_{ij}} +g_{ik}\nabla_jV^k+g_{jk}\nabla_iV^k$.But it's not on book I'm reading.

I also try to compute it according to 
$\mathcal{L}_X\omega=i_Xd\omega+d(i_X\omega)$, but it's seem to be too complex.

What should compute the Lie derivative?  May I have some detail example.

So thanks.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the formula $\mathcal L_X = i_X d+ d i_X$. This formula works only for differential forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider  $g=g^{st}\partial_s\otimes \partial_t$ the use that $\cal L$ is Leibnizian i.e.
$${\cal L}_Vg={\cal L}_V(g^{st}\partial_s\otimes \partial_t),$$
$$={\cal L}_V(g^{st})\partial_s\otimes \partial_t+g^{st}{\cal L}_V(\partial_s)\otimes \partial_t+
g^{st}\partial_s\otimes {\cal L}_V(\partial_t),$$
$$={\cal L}_V(g^{st})\partial_s\otimes \partial_t+g^{st}{\cal L}_V(\partial_s)\otimes \partial_t+
g^{st}\partial_s\otimes {\cal L}_V(\partial_t).$$

Comment: Sorry ,I miss the index of $g_{ij}$. Now ,I have edit it .Besides, the it should be $g=g_{ij}dx^i\bigotimes dx^j$ ?

Comment: also $g=g^{st}\partial_s\otimes \partial_t$, this is the contravariant  form of $g$, the other it is its covariant form. Also it has a mixed form $g={\delta^s}_t\partial_s\otimes dx^t$

Comment: check the last part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Examples

Comment: why the $V^k\nabla_k {g_{ij}}$  vanish?

Comment: it is a result that $\nabla_{\partial k}g=0$